# Saving image in .tif format in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics, computer-vision

I am having trouble saving multiple images with different names in .tif format.
Here is my current code:

```
srcFiles = dir('path/*.tif');
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
  img = strcat('path/',srcFiles(i).name);
  img = imread(img);
  figure, img = imshow(img(:,:,3));
  colormap gray;
  a = strcat(srcFiles(i).name, '-run.tif');
  imwrite(img, a,'tiff');
end
```

I got the following error:

```
Error using imwrite (line 420)
Expected DATA to be one of these types:

numeric, logical

Instead its type was matlab.graphics.primitive.Image.
```

I understand that I'm not saving the image array. However, I'm not sure how to do this since I have to call `colormap gray`. Moreover, I'm doing this using `imwrite` because that eliminates the *white border* that is saved when saving manually. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in 3 consequent lines you're changing the types of the variable `img`:

here it is a char array:

```
img = strcat('path/',srcFiles(i).name);
```

next it is a numeric array (an image):

```
img = imread(img);
```

and finally it is a graphic handle:

```
figure, img = imshow(img(:,:,3));
```

in order to save this image you need to provide `imwrite` with the *numeric array*, the best practice would be to use different names for these variables, like:

```
imgname = strcat('path/',srcFiles(i).name);
img = imread(imgname);
figure, imghandle = imshow(img(:,:,3));
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My fault for the terrible naming conventions. I ran the code and it did fix the error; however, when I save it, it saves the color image. Not the grayscale one.

Comment: i don't know, it depends on the image you're reading from the disk